# Add a space after every character in a string JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

How can i convert a text like `Test` to `T e s t` I know It can probably be done with regex but i don't understand how
I've, Quite new to javascript, in python (Which i quite understand) It can be done with a for loop something like

```py
print(" ".join(a for a in "Test"))
```

But join works differently in javascript and only works for arrays (lists) if i'm right

I've also tried using replace but it does nothing
`console.log("Test".replace(""," "))`

```js
console.log("Test".replace(""," "))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  "Test".split("").join(" ")
  // or
  [..."Test"].join(" ")
```

Thats it. You can't do that with `.join` directly as that only accepts a string.

Comment: Keep in mind: this also adds a space after whitespace characters. Not quite sure, whether that's intended by OP or not.

Comment: @Brainsucker92 Yes, that's what the Python code does as well

Answer (score 3):

JS doesn't support generator expressions, and `join` is an array method that takes the joiner not a string method that takes an iterable. The closest equivalent to your Python code would be

```
console.log(Array.from("Test").join(" "))
```

Using `Array.from` (converting the iterable string to an array) over `.split("")` has the advantage that it doesn't break unicode characters that consist of multiple code points apart.

Comment: For the string `"Tâœest"`, where the "â" uses the combining character U+0302, I obtain exactly the same result with `Array.from("Tâœest").join(" ")`, `"Tâœest".split('').join(" ")`, `"Tâœest".replace(/(?<=.)(?=.)/g, ' ')` and `[..."Tâœest"].join(" ")` with nodejs v10.16.0, i.e.: `'T a ̂ œ e s t'`. In which cases unicode characters are broken?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That's still in the BMP and represented as a single code point in UCS16. Have a look at e.g. [this article](https://dmitripavlutin.com/what-every-javascript-developer-should-know-about-unicode/). I was talking about things like `Array.from("☺️")`.

Comment: Ok, indeed in this case `.split('')` is problematic, and regex alternatives have to use the u modifier.